# Controlling position attribute of a Primefaces Dialog from some central point

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I found this code which positions a PrimeFaces dialog in the top left corner in our project:

```html
<p:dialog styleClass="dialog-top-left" ...>
```

and in the .css file:

```css
.top-left-dialog {
  top: 10px !important;
  left: 10px !important; 
}
```

Now this is clearly wrong (it prevents the dialog from being dragable), you should actually do it like this:

```html
<p:dialog position="top, left" ...>
```

However, the incorrect version using CSS has a nice advantage: I can just change the CSS to change the positioning of all of my dialogs that have the `dialog-top-left` class. Is there a way to also control the `position =`  attribute from some central point (like the .css file for the CSS variant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an [`ApplicationFactory`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/core/globalattributes) for this. In the `ApplicationWrapper` use something like:

```java
@Override
public UIComponent createComponent(FacesContext context, String componentType, String rendererType) {
    final UIComponent component = super.createComponent(context, componentType, rendererType);

    if (component instanceof Dialog) {
        final Dialog dialog = (Dialog) component;
        dialog.setPosition("top, left");
    }

    return component;
}
```

For a complete example follow the linked documentation page.